# Flutter text output not throwing paragraph line when comes from Firebase

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have a Text widget, with \n\n in it to throw a blank line when the paragraph changes:

```
Text('Sibling Rivalry \n\n some more text\n\n> and even more text')
```

This works fine and prints blank lines where the \n\n are defined. However when I try to output the exact same text, but retrieved from Cloud Firestore, the blank lines are not thrown.

Here's the loading code:

```
final extracted = await _firestore
    .collection('items')
    .where("active", isEqualTo: true)
    .orderBy("playCount", descending: true)
    .getDocuments();

extracted.documents.forEach(
  (mediaData) {

    if (mediaData['itemType'] == 'V') {
      loadedMedia.add(
        MediaItem(
          // load fields for VIDEO,
          title: mediaData['title'],
          description: mediaData['description'],
          itemCatCode: mediaData['itemCatCode'],
          imageUrl: mediaData['imageUrl'],
          itemUrl: mediaData['itemUrl'],
          itemType: mediaData['itemType'],
        ),
      );
    }
```

And then I try to output it to screen via the same Text widget:

```
Text(mediaItem.description),
```

Btw I am typing the text directly into Firestore and the description field is defined as String in Firestore. I have no idea why the /n/n is not being recognized as the string coming from Firestore looks exactly the same as the hardcoded string above.

Any help with this would really be greatly appreciated as in the final app, there is a lot of text with quite a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firestore doesn't support any escape sequences within string values. If you write "\n" in a string, you're going to get exactly that back when you read it. If you need to store something special, you may want to encode and decode that yourself.

just do mediaItem.description replace  "\n" with: "\n" again (if you have created string using \n)

One more thing you can try  mediaItem.description replace  "`\\n`" with: "\n" (if it was automatically created using some textarea etc)

Comment: I've tried that: final _reformattedDescription = mediaItem.description.replaceAll("\n", "\n"); Then: Text(_reformattedDescription). But still get just one line with the \n  on the screen

Comment: try mediaItem.description.replaceAll("\\n", "\n")

Comment: Actually I discovered that the important thing was as you mention the double \\. That was really the problem. So good learning for others: all solution split , replace etc should follow e.g. mediaItem.description.replaceAll("\\n, "\n"). Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome @Kitcc.